# Adding new property to DLL

Tags: c++, dll, com, visual-studio-2015

I have created a DLL COM object.

I have used the assistant to define the properties.
Now I would like to add a new property, but I just don't see which item I have to right-click to bring up the "Add property" menu.

Can anyone help?
This is what the hierarchy looks like:

[image]

Comment: You add a property by authoring the .idl. If you cannot do this without the help of an IDE, then you have little chance of solving the more involved issues you'll inevitably encounter. Take a step back, learn COM, learn how to declare COM interfaces and implement COM objects without the IDE, and then move on to using an IDE.

Comment: @IInspectable Your comment is great, can't you make it the answer?

Comment: I don't think my previous comment serves as a good answer. If you believe that comment gave you enough information to answer your question, you could write an answer yourself. Answering your own question is explicitly encouraged on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

To add a new property, switch to Class View. From there, right click on your interface and select Add > Add Property. As already mentioned, you can also edit your idl & CoClass definitions manually.